# why am I getting "TypeError" while creating super user in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am woking on a project where I need to have Django custom model. Based on the documents available I came up with the below code base:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Enter the email before proceeding'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class NewEmployeeProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employee_code = models.IntegerField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)   

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'contact']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

I migrated the model without any hiccups. However, when I am trying to create super user, I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "E:\Django_Projects\Employee_Management_System\EmployeePortal\AUTHENTICATION\models.py", line 17, in create_superuser
    return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "E:\Django_Projects\Employee_Management_System\EmployeePortal\AUTHENTICATION\models.py", line 26, in create_user
    user = self.model(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: NewEmployeeProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_staff'
```

I did come across couple of stackoverflow post, but none of them helped me.

Please suggest, thank you.

New error:

```
ERRORS:
AUTHENTICATION.NewEmployeeProfile.is_superuser: (models.E006) The field 'is_superuser' clashes with the field 'is_superuser' from model 'AUTHENTICATION.newemployeeprofile'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set Fields for is_staff,is_superuser and is_active

```
  class NewEmployeeProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        employee_code = models.IntegerField()
        contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
#add this
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
        objects = AccountManager()
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'contact']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.email)
```

Comment: They are already included in the class AbstractUser.

Comment: But  he is using abstractbaseuser

Comment: AbstractUser =/= AbstractBaseUser

Comment: I know but he has used AbstractBaseUser in his code

Answer (score 0):

Your model `NewEmployeeProfile` inherits from `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin` neither of which have the field `is_staff` or `is_active` (`is_superuser` is present in `PermissionsMixin`), You need to add this field yourself:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class NewEmployeeProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employee_code = models.IntegerField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)   
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'contact']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

Comment: Why not using directly the class `AbstractUser` given by Django ?

Comment: @Henri OP wants to use email as the username field which is why they have overriden `AbstractBaseUser` instead of `AbstractUser`

Comment: it is a bit overkill, there is the option `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Comment: @Henri instead of overkill, I would prefer the term cleaner. If there is a need to inherit from a class and then remove its attributes / methods then the code you write is not very clean. To someone new reading your code `username = None` will not make much sense. It would simply be better for code quality to inherit from somewhere where you don't need to do such things.

Comment: good point ! You are right, it is not the best here to use `AbstractUser`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the definition of your class NewEmployeeProfile.

You should use :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class NewEmployeeProfile(AbstractUser):
   ...
```

You can check the definition of AbstractUser :

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    ...
```

You have the same dependance of your NewEmployeeProfile plus some other fields, including `is_staff`, the one shown in your error message.

DETAILS :
`AbstractUser` is a class given by Django : you are already using `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`, you can add `username = None` if you do not wish to use this field (that is what I do, email is sufficient).

Comment: now when I try AbstractUser instead of the AbstractBaseUser, I am getting a different error. I have updated the original post with new error. I assume that when we are customizing the USer model, and want to use ''email' as username, we need to use AbstractBaseUser. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As a workaround I have added the ''is_staff" in model. But I feel, its not the right way. Because, If I let a normal user register in the web application having the  ''is_staff", it will lead to a security breach.

Comment: You can check the answer of @Abdul about the difference of `AbstractBaseUser` and `AbstractUser`, he made me change my mind.
About the `is_staff` in model, that is why you have the manager : to block a user to have `is_staff=True`. Besides that, you must implement some security measures in the admin and view part.